# Changing source address of ICMP packets from 1 interface to another

Tags: linux, networking, icmp

In my box, I have two ethernet interfaces. Due to the constraints of the system I am dealing with, I need all ICMP response messages to have the source address of 1 of the interfaces.

An example:

A packet with a TTL of 0 comes in on interface 0, it gets dropped and an ICMP response is generated with the source address of 0 and is routed out 0. Another packet comes in with a TTL of 0 on interface 1, it gets dropped and an ICMP response is generated. Instead of the source address being interface 1, I need it to be interface 0 and still be routed out interface 1. Is this possible?

I don't want it to affect the source addresses of other protocols coming out of either interface.

**Edit:**

Here is the current setup of the particular box:

ip -br link

```
lo           UNKNOWN   00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP>
sit0@NONE    DOWN      0.0.0.0 <NOARP>
np0          UNKNOWN   <POINTTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP>
np1          UNKNOWN   <POINTTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP>
eth0         UP        <POINTTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

ip -4 -br addr

```
lo           UNKNOWN   127.0.0.1/8
np0          UNKNOWN   192.0.0.1/24
np1          UNKNOWN   192.10.1.1/24
eth0         UP        193.10.1.1/24
```

ip route

```
default dev np1 scope linke
192.0.0.0/24 dev np0 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.0.1
192.10.1.0/24 dev np1 proto kernel scope link src 192.10.1.1
193.10.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 193.10.1.1
```

The system is not setup to run a VPN. The system has 1 physical ethernet (eth0) and 2 virtual ethernet interfaces (np0 and np1).

Using the naming from above, let interface 0 be eth0 and interface 1 be np1

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide your current setup on this box (eg: `ip -br link; ip -4 -br addr; ip route`)? You can obfuscate public addresses (eg: using dedicated 192.0.2.0/24 or 198.51.100.0/24) if needed. This would make easier to illustrate an explanation and avoid missing something that wouldn't be expected. Details might matter for this. Especially if you omitted some information (eg: using a VPN, etc.)

Comment: No information to provide? Not interested anymore?

Comment: Sorry, I got caught up with work and couldn't get access to the box. I have updated the question with system configuration

Comment: I wonder why the obfuscation is so obfuscate: obviously above eth0 is not Ethernet but a layer 3 interface (with a tunnel going on) or it wouldn't be POINTOPOINT + NOARP.

Comment: 193.10.1.0/24 is managed by SUNET in Sweden

Comment: @ChrisDavies I wished OP to use [RFC 5737 addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737.html#section-3), but OP didn't take the hint.

Comment: @A.B yes, the documentation ranges are really useful for denoting external IP addresses, etc

Comment: I think `iptables` can do what you want. There is a `SNAT` target for rewriting addresses and you can match on the `icmp` protocol. I don't know enough to easily construct the rule though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Routing rules based on L4 protocol

Linux [kernel >= 4.17](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.17#Networking) can do policy routing based on IP's layer 4 protocol:

> - Extends fib rule match support to include sport, dport and **ip proto
>   match** (to complete the 5-tuple match support). Common use-cases of
>   Policy based routing in the data center require 5-tuple match
>
> [...]

Initially, any ICMP response generated from the system (named *Box*) back toward the original source node would use the address on the interface facing this source just like any emitted traffic from the host to this node.

```shell
# ip route get to 192.10.1.201
192.10.1.201 dev np1 src 192.10.1.1 uid 0 
    cache 
# ip route get to 193.10.1.200
193.10.1.200 dev eth0 src 193.10.1.1 uid 0 
    cache
```

One can add a routing table that will present a duplicated but modified entry of the relevant route, with a different hinted source address than what would normally be used, then select this routing table with a routing rule, but only when the protocol is ICMP. Note that this routing table should be populated after addresses and (normal) routes are configured, so it won't be rejected as an impossible route when added. As usual if this route disappears for any reason (eg: interface brought down then up), contrary to `proto kernel` routes in the main routing table, it won't be added back: it must be added again whenever such event happens.

Here the behavior to change on the duplicated route for traffic that goes out using the `np1` interface is to hint a different source address (193.10.1.1 instead of 192.10.1.1):

```
ip route add 192.10.1.0/24 dev np1 src 193.10.1.1 table 1000
```

And this should be applied to override the *main* table for ICMP only:

```
ip rule add pref 100 ipproto icmp lookup 1000
```

Nothing changes for non-ICMP traffic to `np1`:

```shell
# ip route get to 192.10.1.201
192.10.1.101 dev np1 src 192.10.1.1 uid 0 
    cache
```

but does for ICMP traffic to `np1`:

```shell
# ip route get to 192.10.1.201 ipproto icmp
192.10.1.201 dev np1 table 1000 src 193.10.1.1 uid 0 
    cache
```

So the two cases in OP's question are fulfilled: ICMP, such as ICMP Time exceeded, are replied from hinted `eth0`'s address whether replying on `eth0` or on `np1`.

This also affects locally-initiated ICMP such as pings (but see later).

---

### Caveat and details

- caveat: (layer 2) Ethernet interfaces and ARP

  If `np1` were an Ethernet interface, ARP requests directly triggered from such ICMP errors also follow routing rules and will appear above as requesting for example 192.10.1.201 from 193.10.1.1 rather than from 192.10.1.1, but only if there's no ARP entry for the node existing yet on *Box* and if the node didn't do itself an ARP request to resolve *Box* right before (ie this will happen only if the node did have *Box* in ARP cache but *Box* didn't have the node in ARP cache, which usually is not the case). Other Linux systems won't care by default (they follow the weak [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model) and accept any such ARP requests by default). Some other OS might care and not reply this single "wrong" ARP request.

  If this really matters, this already rare case can be completely prevented with [`arp_announce=1`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1614):

  > ```
  > - 1 - Try to avoid local addresses that are not in the target's
  >   subnet for this interface. [...]
  > ```

  So for the `np1` interface:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.np1.arp_announce=1
  ```
- The `ping` command will also use the changed source address

  `ping` is not an ICMP response, so should be left alone working as usual.

  One can still restrict the ICMP types (and codes) affected with a not-really-documented option: by mapping ICMP type+code as destination port in the routing rule's selector, according to how it's handled in sources:

  [`include/net/flow.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/net/flow.h?h=v6.1#n46):

  > ```c
  > union flowi_uli {
  >     struct {
  >         __be16  dport;
  >         __be16  sport;
  >     } ports;
  >
  >     struct {
  >         __u8    type;
  >         __u8    code;
  >     } icmpt;
  > ```

  > ```c
  > union flowi_uli     uli;
  > #define fl4_sport       uli.ports.sport
  > #define fl4_dport       uli.ports.dport
  > #define fl4_icmp_type       uli.icmpt.type
  > #define fl4_icmp_code       uli.icmpt.code
  > ```

  [`net/ipv4/fib_rules.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/fib_rules.c?h=v6.1#n199):

  > ```c
  >     if (fib_rule_port_range_set(&rule->dport_range) &&
  >         !fib_rule_port_inrange(&rule->dport_range, fl4->fl4_dport))
  >         return 0;
  > ```

  Because of the union, `fl4->fl4_dport` <=> `fl4_icmp_type * 256 + fl4_icmp_code`: `ip rule ... ipproto icmp dport ...` can be used for type+code which doesn't have a dedicated syntax.

  So just limiting it to anything but type 8 (ICMP request) means limiting it to 0-7 + 9-255. Once multiplied by 256 and adequate end interval adjusted (+255) this gives 1-2047 (because 0 is invalid, starting at 1. ICMP reply which is type 0 code 0 won't match but doesn't have to match, because as an actual reply it will never use the hinted source, but the actual local destination that was used in the remote ICMP request and that will be used as reply source) + 2304-65534 (ditto for 65535). Starting from the original routing rule:

  > ```
  > ip rule add pref 100 ipproto icmp lookup 1000
  > ```

  - either replace it with two rules:

    ```
    ip rule del pref 100

    ip rule add pref 100 ipproto icmp dport 1-2047 lookup 1000
    ip rule add pref 101 ipproto icmp dport 2304-65534 lookup 1000
    ```
  - or else keep the initial rule and add rules around it to skip it (could have been simplified to only 2048 since ICMP Echo request's code is always 0):

    ```
    ip rule del pref 100
    ip rule del pref 101

    ip rule add pref 100 ipproto icmp lookup 1000
    ip rule add pref 101 lookup 424242
    ip rule add pref 99 ipproto icmp dport 2048-2303 goto 101
    ```

  With either choices a `ping` command won't be changed anymore:

  ```shell
  # ip route get to 192.10.1.201 ipproto icmp dport 2048
  192.10.1.201 dev np1 src 192.10.1.1 uid 0 
      cache
  ```

  ICMP redirect (type 5) should probably also be added to the exceptions in a similar way.